# Autocomplete search with jquery and AJAX in django webapp

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to implement an autocomplete search by following this tutorial

https://medium.com/@ninajlu/django-ajax-jquery-search-autocomplete-d4b4bf6494dd

And i am failing to implement it, and i think it has something to do with my urls or the way i am putting scripts in my .html file.

My search bar is in my index view

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'KPI/style.css' %}">

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: "/login/index",
                minLength: 2,
                open: function(){
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99);
                    }, 0);
                }
              });

        });

</script>

<form id="search" method="POST" action="{% url 'kpi:search' %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'kpi'
urlpatterns = [
 path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
 path('login/index/', views.IndexView.as_view()),
]
```

now in the tutorial it says to put this path `url(r'^ajax_calls/search/', autocompleteModel),` but it doesn't seem like the path has to be this way, so i changed the path to `login/index/` and called the class view `IndexView` which holds the autocompleteModel like so

views.py

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'KPI/index.html'

    def autocompleteModel(self,request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            q = request.GET.get('term', '').capitalize()
            search_qs = Epic.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
            results = []
            print(q)
            for r in search_qs:
                results.append(r.name)
            data = json.dumps(results)
        else:
            data = 'fail'
        mimetype = 'application/json'
        return JsonResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Epic is the model i am searching on with the value `name`.

with the code i have above it doesn't do anything, and i'm hoping someone can see a flaw in it.

Comment: why are you sending HTTP response, for the ajax request you should be sending a json response to the frontend which can render your reponse in autocomplete

Comment: Yeah i overlooked that part of the tutorial and changed it to JsonResponse, should i be passing any context to the templates in order to show the data for the search bar?

Comment: possible like this `return JsonResponse({'name':'data'})`